Logical Volume LVM in External Disk 8T data storage, how to put back and mirgate into new host server?
I recently moved to a new LVM host server, following LVM instructions that export and import which are successful. All lv are in an external disk(8T NAS)
Qemu libvirt network bridge0 setup is working normally. The command Vgchange activates and lvs are normal, the storage details of the vg group shows too.
However, the lsblk shows all the vg and lv, the QEMU///SYSTEM is EMPTY, virsh command cannot open any lv and error no VG group found.
I searched for a few days and still can't find any solution.
Thanks
The screenshot below: VM manager empty  ($USER and root open still same)
VM manager VM list empty
VM storage vm detail
VG path in the server
UPDATE QUESTION help help help: How to put back all lvm into KVM virt-manager?

New reinstall ubuntu 24.04 lvm server and kvm in the host server.
Still cannot migrate make it in virt-manager.


pvs vgs lvs 
virsh list --all
update: this is screenshot of pvs,vgs,lvs, all the lvm data in external nas sdb.
network qemu///system is connected, virsh list --all are empty.

what does LVM instructions that export and import ... export and import what exactly? what instructions have you followed to copy the VM configurations?

the image shows many volumes in the LVM volume group - so your title "can't see LVM list" is wrong - one odd thing, both sdb and sdb1 are shown to be a LVM volume group - that looks wrong - how can a whole disk be a VG and a partition on that disk also be a VG

Step by step  vgchange -an, vgexport shutdown machine. than  sudo lvm vgimport vg_kvm in a new Server.

still nothing to do with QEMU in that - how did you migrate them

no! didn't do any migrate yet, just doing some test to create new vm using the existing lvm voloume, however network bridge0 not assigned IP. Does it have to do migrate lvm to a new host server? please instruct me thanks

where did you try to create new vm? Everything you said is about migrating the storage, nothing to do with VM's - but your title says QEMU can't see the storage, yet the image shows at least 9 volumes visible - so it's kind of hard to know what isn't working

OK! How to do the migration in my case? thanks

not sure why you posted an answer ... but virsh list --all shows you have no VM's setup - which is why you don't have any VM's running ... you need to migrate the VM's (Virtual Machines) which is a different step to migrating LVM (i.e. the Logical Volumes in LVM) ... i.e. VM and LVM are unrelated
